# Getting the the value of a Key without know the name of the key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object like this:

```
var foo = { 'bar' : 'baz' }
```

*bar* can be any word, I need to read *baz*. Since the object is always like this (one row) I find making an each cycle inefficient.

```
$.each( body.message, function( key, value ) { 
  alert(value);
}
```

Is there an smart way of doing this?

Comment: "Inefficient" how?  As in, ugly code?  Inefficient to type out?  Actual CPU performance is not something you need to worry about (unless you're doing this 1000 times a second, at which point you might have other issues in your design :p).

Comment: as of JavaScript 1.8.5 you can use Object.keys(obj)

Comment: @Engineer Dollery et al: This was not a duplicate of that question as the OP only wants a specific (first) property name. The answers on the dupe are not appropriate. Scimonster's answer below is appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Object.keys()` to list the keys, and get it from there.

```
foo[Object.keys(foo)[0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use a for loop: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/s2745674/1/

```
var foo = { 'bar' : 'baz' }

for (var key in foo)
{
    alert(key);
}
```

For a single item (as specified) you won't notice a speed decrease (heck for loads of items you would notice it) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = { 'bar' : 'baz' };

for(var key in foo)
{
    if (foo.hasOwnProperty(key)){
         // use key for the key and foo[key] for the value.        
         console.log('key: ' + key + ' value: ' + foo[key]); // key: bar value: baz
    }
}
```

Comment: Bit of overkill as the OP specified the object had one property only.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - It looked like an example to me..

Comment: "Since the object is always like this (one row) I find making an each cycle inefficient." :) (and thanks for reminding me to scope my own `for` var)

Comment: If so, `Object.keys(foo)[0]` is the best answer here :)

Comment: I am not going to argue with that... I just posted the simpler alternative (as you did) :)

Comment: And BTW you can always make it ugly by adding a break as the last line in the loop...

Comment: Also true, but pointless if there is indeed only one property. I should add that as a note :)